# Disks utility options for automounting hard disk with rw rights

Tags: hard-drive, fstab, automount, udisks

I am on Ubuntu 20.04.1 and I have a second hard drive: sdb1 (named mee_2) with one partition (FAT32). I used 'disks' to auto-mount it at start up.
BUT as user I can not write on it... Which are the correct options to use when configuring auto-mount?

My last try was:
`user,rw,nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-name=mee_2,x-gvfs-icon=mee_2,x-gvfs-symbolic-icon=mee_2,x-gvfs-show,`

[image]

Comment: FAT32 not recommended for larger partitions. It has no journel so recovery may be slow or impossible and it cannot store any file over 4GB. My ESP is mounted at `/dev/nvme0n1p1 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)` But if Windows also mounts your Windows type partitions, it may set hibernation flag preventing read/write access.

Comment: i only use it for temporary media files - recovery is not important. also use it with linux only - single boot...file max size not important either. can you provide the syntax for my case maybe? do i need to use masking somehow???

Comment: If media file is over 4GB you will lose it. Have you tried the defaults that Ubuntu assigns as I posted. I would expect those to work. Settings details: https://mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/filesystems/vfat.txt I believe I used this once, but normally do not use FAT32/vfat: `UUID=46CD-C9B2 /home/fred/share vfat user,auto,fmask=0113,dmask=0002 0 0` Also example of vfat here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions#FAT32

Comment: i used the settings described in the second link and it works. what filesystem do you suggest instead of FAT32?

Comment: I use ext4, but if I need compatibility with Windows then NTFS. But with Windows you must not let Windows set hibernation flag with either hibernation or fast start up. And Windows turns fast start up back on with updates, setting hibernation flag and locking all NTFS partitions. The Linux NTFS driver will only read hibernated partitions to prevent damage. Some have managed to write into hibernated NTFS and data is just lost as Windows restores from hibernation file structure.